# Syntax Error in React Component render Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The `render` method in the React component looks like this:

```
render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
}
```

The error is this:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
              SyntaxError: Unexpected token    20 |    21 |     render() { > 22
              |         return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
              |
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "babel-version": "babel --version"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
       "env",
       "react",
       "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "less": "^3.8.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.3",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "npm": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the whole class:

```
export default class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: ""
        };      
    }

    handleNameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
}
```

Note the class doesn't make sense in terms of functionality at the moment because I've been experimenting to figure out the syntax error.

I have a `.babelrc` also:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-class-properties"]
  ]
}
```

The method is pretty straightforward, so I can't see what the issue is. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I feel like there's an error with your class syntax not your JSX. Could you put your whole class?

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: Class properties (`handleNameChange = (e) => { ... };`) is a [stage 2](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2.html) proposal, so you most likely have to use `"presets": [ "env", "react", "stage-2" ]`

Comment: I think you shouldn't have the trailing semi colon after `handleNameChange`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli That is perfectly valid, and often recommended.

Comment: @Tholle's comment is likely correct. Also, if/when you enable class properties you can just write `state = {}` directly on the class as well.

Comment: I tried @Tholle's suggestion, but it didn't help. I then installed `babel-preset-stage-2` and added `"presets": ["stage-2"]` to `.babelrc` but to no avail.

Comment: Also to note: using stage presets (e.g. "stage-2") it  planned to be deprecated in Babel 7. You might want to look at including "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties" specifically instead.

Comment: That's actually already in there.

Comment: Are you using both a `.babelrc` and the `babel` field in `package.json`?

Comment: Yes. I just uninstalled `babel-preset-stage-2` and the `.babelrc` config associated with it. The current file has been added to the question. Meanwhile, the `babel` entry in `package.json` is `["env", "react", "stage-2"]`

Comment: Just to clarify, does your .babelrc have "presets": {"react", "env"] ?

Comment: No. The entire `.babelrc` is above. However, those presets, and now `stage-2` thanks to @Tholle, are in `package.json`.

Comment: I'm not sure what config takes precedence, but I think it's best *just* to use `.babelrc`, and remove the `babel` field in `package.json` entirely, so you just have one config. You can try `"presets": [ "env", "react", "stage-2"]` in the `.babelrc` instead.

Comment: That worked--once I reinstalled `babel-preset-stage-2`. No syntax errors. Thank you all for your patience. I'm curious though about what @SamVK said. Aren't these presets in `.babelrc` deprecated?

Comment: They are being removed in babel 7. You're using babel 6, where they still exist.

Comment: Yeah, that's what *deprecated* means--not gone yet but on the way out and therefore not the best idea for new code. How can I solve this problem in a more durable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely getting the error because the class property above (`handleNameChange = (e) => { ... };`) is a [stage 2 proposal](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2.html).

If you install `babel-preset-stage-2` and add it to your `.babelrc` the error should be resolved.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", "react", "stage-2"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Aren't these presets in `.babelrc` deprecated? Is there a more durable solution?

Comment: @Vidya I'm not sure I would use the word deprecated. The entire preset system is getting redone for Babel 7, but to my knowledge there is no alternative yet for Babel 6.

Comment: Ahh OK. Thanks.

Comment: @Vidya Stage presets are being deprecated in Babel 7. The alternative is to simply include the all plugins those presets come with - or more specifically, only the plugins you need. (So in this case, if all you need is `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` you'd just include that.)
See https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/48fe688a10d83486defdda223ac8d8d88057975d/packages/babel-preset-stage-0/README.md#babelpreset-stage-0

Comment: That plugin was already included from the beginning. If I have `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` *and* `babel-preset-stage-2` and factor the `.babelrc` presets out into `package.json`, things fail again. I have to say that modern JS engineering is tougher than I expected. I can see why TypeScript, Reason, and Elm are so compelling.